# How to Properly set Calender Pro In an ExJS APP

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to setup Calender Pro from http://ext.ensible.com/products/calendar/ into my app but It is not working.
I have downloaded the proect and copied the src and examples to a package extensible/src and extensible/examples respectively. Then added this to my View.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false,
    paths: {
        "Extensible": "/extensible/src/",
        "Extensible.example": "/extensible/example/"
    }
});

Ext.define('myview',
    requires : [
        'Ext.tab.Panel',
        'Extensible.calendar.data.MemoryEventStore',
        'Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel',
        'Extensible.example.calendar.data.Events'],
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'extensible.calendarpanel',
            title: 'Calendar',

            width: 700,
            height: 500,
            activeItem: 1
        }
    ]
);
```

This does not work by throws a **Uncaught TypeError: c is not a constructor**.
Creating a componet Dynamiccaly throws another error, **Extensible is undefined.**

Has anyone configured this component with EX JS version 6.00 or know a better option that will display events calender in extjs?

Comment: ExtJs 6.2 has build in calendar http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.calendar.panel.Panel.html example http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/calendar/ however it's only as part of the highest license version.

Comment: The Issue is that we have been using 6.0, And becuase of the license, I am trying to use Calender Pro

Comment: Since the site you linked to explicitly states that CalendarPro "Only works with Ext JS version 4.x and below.", I fear that we cannot help you. There were really many breaking changes between 4 and 5, and also some from 5 to 6.